# HTTP Request with No HTTP Response

Tags: php, android, mysql, httprequest, httpresponse

I just need to know what i'm missing in my application
My Android Application sends username and password as HTTP POST then PHP file responds with values from database for that username 
The problem is when i enter username and password nothing comes back in Toast it's not even displayed

MainActivity

```
package com.example.postapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      TextView tv;
      EditText u,p;
      Button login;
      String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), u.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(u.getText().toString(),p.getText().toString());

            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{
        String host;


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean a= postData(params[0],params[1]);       
            return a;
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean localres){
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
             if (localres){
                    tv.setText("A Correct Username and Password");
                }else{
                    tv.setText("Incorrect Username or Password");
                }
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(host!=null)
                {
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), host.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        public Boolean postData(String a,String b) {
             // ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //  postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", a));
             // postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", b));
              HttpURLConnection connection;
              OutputStreamWriter request = null;

                   URL url = null;   
                   String response = null;         
                   String parameters = "username="+a+"&password="+b;   

                   try
                   {
                       url = new URL("http://"+"192.168.1.3"+"/new/check2.php");
                       connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       connection.setDoOutput(true);
                       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                       connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                       request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                       request.write(parameters);
                       request.flush();
                       request.close();            
                       String line = "";               
                       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                       {
                           sb.append(line + "\n");
                       }
                       // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                       response = sb.toString();
                       // You can perform UI operations here
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
                       isr.close();
                       reader.close();

                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   return true;
           }


        }



    }
```

PHP

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "pet_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'")or die (mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($count > 0) {
    echo $row['filter_st'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['heat_st'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['led_st'];
} else {
    echo 0;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Logcat appears there is an exception

```
12-13 20:57:45.534: W/System.err(14768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-13 20:57:45.534: W/System.err(14768):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
12-13 20:57:45.534: W/System.err(14768):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at com.example.postapp.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.postData(MainActivity.java:136)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at com.example.postapp.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at com.example.postapp.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-13 20:57:45.538: W/System.err(14768):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();
```

You have

```
Boolean a= postData(params[0],params[1]); // in doInbackground
```

In `public Boolean postData(String a,String b)` you display toast which is wrong

You are Updating ui in the background thread which is not possible. Update ui on the ui thread.

Return result in `doInbackground`. The result of `doInbackground` computation is param to `onPostExecute`. So based on the result you can update ui ie display toast accordingly.

or use `runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show(); 
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In above code not allowed Toast message becz you have not to load in doInBackground. if you have to show toast then storing any variable after showing the toast in **onPostExecute()** method in AsyncTask class

i.e In above post data method adding comment
    // You can perform UI operations here
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message from Server: \n"+ response,0).show();
//storing response to any variable

//In post data response
**String message=response;**

> protected void onPostExecute(Boolean localres){
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), **message**, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>   }

2) other Way is 
you have to Toast message in **runonUIThread** in doInBackground method.